# how to use the output/value of variable in python

Tags: python, variables

I'm learning python.  So here's what I'm after:

Inside a python script I have the following:

```
back_minutes1 = int(sys.argv[2])
back_minutes = timedelta(minutes=back_minutes)
```

This works fine, but I'm essentially creating a 'trash variable' to make it work.  If this were say bash, I could probably do something like

```
back_minutes = timedelta(minutes=`int(sys.argv[2])`)
```

This, of course doesn't work.  What's the pythonic way to do this without creating this throw-away variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not

```
back_minutes = timedelta(minutes=int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: Oh good grief!  I could have sworn I tried that.  I can't believe it just worked.  How embarrassing.  I'll mark your answer as correct once it allows me.  Thanks... :)

Comment: Not a problem, if your looking for proper command line arguments use argparse in python 2.7+